# Connecting to a Cisco ASA 5510 with Win 7 VPN client

Tags: windows-7, cisco-asa, cisco-vpn, vpn

Is it possible to configure a Cisco ASA 5510 to accept a connection from Windows 7 with the built in VPN client software in Win7 ?

I know this [question has sorta-been asked before](https://serverfault.com/questions/287547/does-windows-7-vpn-work-with-a-cisco-asa-5510) on SF but I'm hoping that somethings have changed since then?

What I'm confused about is that the built in Windows 7 VPN client has support for

- SSTP
- PPTP
- L2TP/IPSec

and with 3 options .. surely the Cisco ASA must be able to support one of those??

Answer (score 0):

Yes the cisco asa 5500 series can support l2tp/ipsec firewalls and the native windows client can be used to connect to them.